# Actionscript3 - Using a button to switch between images

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm opening a new flex project in Flash builder and I'm trying to make an interface with 3 buttons, "cat", "dog", and "bird." When each of the buttons are pressed, I would like an image box on the bottom of the screen to fill in with the appropriate animal's image.

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to display an image in AS3. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should try to google for such basic things. There is plenty information on the topic

Answer (score -1):

One of the simplest way would be, if you don't mind your swf to embed the three images:

embed code

```
[Embed(source="/../assets/cat.jpg")]
static private const Cat:Class;
[Embed(source="/../assets/dog.jpg")]
static private const Cat:Class;
[Embed(source="/../assets/bird.jpg")]
static private const Cat:Class;
```

container initialization

```
private var imageBox:Sprite = new Sprite;
// initialize imagebox position/chose parent here, for instance:
container.addChild(imageBox);
```

cat button click handler

```
imageBox.removeChildren();
imageBox.addChild(new Cat);
```

dog button click handler

```
imageBox.removeChildren();
imageBox.addChild(new Dog);
```

bird button click handler

```
imageBox.removeChildren();
imageBox.addChild(new Bird);
```

I'm assuming your project has "assets" & "src" directories, containing respectively your images and your as3 code